# Convert Json to Html - below json i will get from server, i want to display it as html table

Tags: php, html, json

```
{"status":"OK","data":{"train_number":"11111","chart_prepared":false,"pnr_number":"4259444444","train_name":"AAA","travel_date":{"timestamp":1394841600,"date":"10-4-2014"},"from":{"code":"ABC","name":"CITYJUNCTION","time":"20:30"},"to":{"code":"XYZ","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"alight":{"code":"DDD","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"board":{"code":"ABC","name":"FFF","time":"20:30","timestamp":1394895600},"class":"SL","passenger":[{"seat_number":"S7 , 11,GN","status":"CNF"},{"seat_number":"S7 , 06,GN","status":"CNF"}]}}
```

Comment: use json_decode(json_data,true); loop through it and display !!

Comment: use json_decode() and print using php

Comment: Either use `json_decode()` and spit it out using PHP or use JQuery and help parse out the JSON while writing the values dynamically to your HTML

Comment: PHP has a function for this - `json_decode()` - http://uk1.php.net/json_decode which will return an `object`, which you can loop over and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to convert the json string to an object or associative array, you may then iterate over the result. Remember to use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) to escape the data.

This should help get you started:

```
function table_encode(array $array) {
    $buffer = '<table border="1"><thead>';
    foreach (array_keys($array) as $header) {
        $buffer .= '<th style="text-align:left">' . htmlspecialchars($header) . '</th>';
    }
    $buffer .= '</thead><tbody><tr>';
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $buffer .= '<td>';
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $buffer .= table_encode($value);
        } else {
            $buffer .= htmlspecialchars($value);
        }
        $buffer .= '</td>';
    }
    $buffer .= '</tbody></table>';
    return $buffer;
}

$json = '{"status":"OK","data":{"train_number":"11111","chart_prepared":false,"pnr_number":"4259444444","train_name":"AAA","travel_date":{"timestamp":1394841600,"date":"10-4-2014"},"from":{"code":"ABC","name":"CITYJUNCTION","time":"20:30"},"to":{"code":"XYZ","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"alight":{"code":"DDD","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"board":{"code":"ABC","name":"FFF","time":"20:30","timestamp":1394895600},"class":"SL","passenger":[{"seat_number":"S7 , 11,GN","status":"CNF"},{"seat_number":"S7 , 06,GN","status":"CNF"}]}}';
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$html = table_encode($json['data']);
echo $html;
```

Comment: Great ! it worked . Thanks alot Andrew. I dint try other codes. But i would like to thank all of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = json_decode($array);//Decode Json
eccho($json);
function eccho($json){
foreach ($json as $file)
{
if(is_array($file))
 return eccho($json);
else
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> $file </td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

}
```

maybe this is useful for you...

Answer (score 0):

you can't convert direct in to html.. 
use can use **json_decode()** function to convert it in to php array like follow or else use parse the json in jquery/javascript..

```
    $var = '{"status":"OK","data":{"train_number":"11111","chart_prepared":false,"pnr_number":"4259444444","train_name":"AAA","travel_date":{"timestamp":1394841600,"date":"10-4-2014"},"from":{"code":"ABC","name":"CITYJUNCTION","time":"20:30"},"to":{"code":"XYZ","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"alight":{"code":"DDD","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"board":{"code":"ABC","name":"FFF","time":"20:30","timestamp":1394895600},"class":"SL","passenger":[{"seat_number":"S7 , 11,GN","status":"CNF"},{"seat_number":"S7 , 06,GN","status":"CNF"}]}}';

    $ab = json_decode($var,true);
    print_r($ab); // here u will get your json data in php array. so now you can print it in html based on your requirements..
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If your get response form server  through AJAX then use

```
var json = '{"status":"OK","data":{"train_number":"11111","chart_prepared":false,"pnr_number":"4259444444","train_name":"AAA","travel_date":{"timestamp":1394841600,"date":"10-4-2014"},"from":{"code":"ABC","name":"CITYJUNCTION","time":"20:30"},"to":{"code":"XYZ","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"alight":{"code":"DDD","name":"TTR","time":"05:35"},"board":{"code":"ABC","name":"FFF","time":"20:30","timestamp":1394895600},"class":"SL","passenger":[{"seat_number":"S7 , 11,GN","status":"CNF"},{"seat_number":"S7 , 06,GN","status":"CNF"}]}}';
obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

or use

```
data = eval( '(' + json + ')');
```

Now you can access

```
var status = data.status;
```

and you can easily display display data in html.